# API Request Pagination

Tags: api, reactjs, github, axios

I am making a simple API request to Github to get all the repositories. The problem is that Github has a limitation and the max that it can send is 100 per request. There are users that have more than 100 repositories and I don't know how to access it or how to make pagination.

I am making GET request with Axios like this:

```
https://api.github.com/users/<AccountName>/repos?per_page=100
```

I can also put page number like so

```
https://api.github.com/users/<AccountName>/repos?page=3&per_page=100
```

But how do I make this work in app without making 10 API requests? I wouldn't even know how many requests I should make because I don't know what is the number that gets returned, does somebody have 100 or 1000 repos? I would like for everything to be returned and saved in array, for example.

EDIT:
Example: I am passing in accountName

```
var config = {
  headers: {'Authorization': `token ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`}
}

const REQUEST: string = 'https://api.github.com/users/'

const apiCall = {
  getData: async function (accountName) {
    const encodedAccountName = encodeURIComponent(accountName)
    const requestUrl = `${REQUEST}${encodedAccountName}`

    const user = await axios.get(requestUrl, config)
// This return user and inside of user there is a link for fetching repos
    const repo = await axios.get(`${user.data.repos_url}?per_page=100`, config)

    ...
```

Comment: Do you have any code and have you tried doing a sleep on the requests?

Comment: Hi Mike Tunk. I updated the question with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the repo count by requesting from the user account URL first. For example here is mine:

https://api.github.com/users/erikh2000

The response there includes a "public_repos" value. Bam! That's the magic number you want.

You next need to make multiple fetches if the repo count is over 100. I know you didn't want to, but hey... can't blame web services for trying to conserve their bandwidth. The good news is you can probably put them in a Promise.all() block and have them all fetch together and return at once. So code like...

```
const fetchAllTheRepos = (userName, repoCount) => {
  const MAX_PER_PAGE = 100;
  const baseUrl = 'https://api.github.com/users/' + userName +
    '/repos?per_page=' + MAX_PER_PAGE;

  //Start fetching every page of repos.
  const fetchPromises = [], pageCount = Math.ceil(repoCount / 
    MAX_PER_PAGE);
  for (let pageI = 1; pageI <= pageCount; ++pageI) {
    const fetchPagePromise = fetch(baseUrl + '&page=' + pageI);
    fetchPromises.push(fetchPagePromise);
  }

  //This promise resolves after all the fetching is done.
  return Promise.all(fetchPromises)
  .then((responses) => {
     //Parse all the responses to JSON.
     return Promise.all( responses.map((response) => response.json()) );
  }).then((results) => {
    //Copy the results into one big array that has all the friggin repos.
    let repos = [];
    results.forEach((result) => {
      repos = repos.concat(result);
    });
    return repos;
  });
};

//I left out the code to get the repo count, but that's pretty easy.
fetchAllTheRepos('erikh2000', 7).then((repos) => {
    console.log(repos.length);
});
```

Simultaneously fetching all the pages may end up being more than Github wants to let you do at once for those accounts with lots of repos. I would put some "good citizen" limit on the number of repos you'll try to get at once, e.g. 1000. And then see if api.github.com agrees with your definition of a good citizen by watching for HTTP error responses. You can get into throttling solutions if needed, but probably a "grab it all at once" approach like above works fine.

On the other hand, if you are spidering through multiple accounts in one session, then maybe design the throttling in from the beginning just to you know... be nice. For that, look at a queue/worker pattern.

Comment: Thank Erik. I will examine this. Yes, I am also first fetching User and then from user I take the link and fetch repositories. I updated the question with my code example. I will try to incoporate yours now. Let's bring the baby home. If you also have proposition how to incoporate mine with yours example please write it here. I am little out of water here.

Comment: I also found out that there is an npm package `parse-link-header` that parses returned header and inside the header there is a total amount of pages and a link for the next page that you can put in api call and get the data. Not sure how would I use that still, maybe somekind of loop.

Comment: Igor, I think you have all the pieces. I don't want to convert my code to Axios fetches, but I assume the ES6 fetches translate over with a little thought. Your request to the user URL (const user = await axios.get(requestUrl, config)) will give you the repo count (user.data.public_repos), and then you need the same logic as presented in my fetchAllTheRepos() function above.

Comment: Thanks Erik. I did it. Your logic worked great, I just coverted to axios and async/await. Thanks.