# fetch all github repo by Github api v3 and javascript

Tags: github, github-api

I discovered that by default the API responds with 30 repos.

May I know how should I use for loop to retrieve all repos?

```
const axios = require('axios');
const repoUrl = `https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/repos`;

access_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
// console.log
const config = {
    headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`}     # only 30   
};




axios.get(repoUrl, null, config).then((responses) => {

    const repos = responses.data.map(({name, language, html_url, created_at, description}) => {
        return {name, language, html_url, created_at, description};
    })

    console.log("number of repo  ", repos.length);


}).catch(error => {
    console.log(`getrepos error: ${error}`)
});
```

by    https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repositories-for-the-authenticated-user--parameters  , there is a page parameter

but how should I write the for loop?   should I loop the page with 1,2,3,4.... until server give me some error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a [GraphQL query](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql) with Axios, as [in this example](https://gist.github.com/benj3/3f57f6c3ab2ef16ce1a594191e79cb52), or in [this article](https://dev.to/thomasaudo/get-started-with-github-grapql-api--1g8b):

```
axios({
  url: 'https://graphql.com/graphql',
  method: 'post',
  data: {
    query: `
     query {
       viewer {
         repositories(isFork: false) {
           totalCount
         }
       }
    }`
  }
}).then((result) => {
  console.log(result.data)
});
```

Once you have the total number of repositories, you start looping (only the exact amount of loop), as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44103122/6309):

```js
  //Start fetching every page of repos.
  const fetchPromises = [], pageCount = Math.ceil(repoCount / 
    MAX_PER_PAGE);
  for (let pageI = 1; pageI <= pageCount; ++pageI) {
    const fetchPagePromise = fetch(baseUrl + '&page=' + pageI);
    fetchPromises.push(fetchPagePromise);
  }
```